# We keep reading about 1M TPS on Layer2 but wouldnt that be super expensive? Alone for every rollup to lock 10k Tezos sounds not realistic?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

We keep reading about 1M TPS on Layer2 but wouldnt that be super expensive? Alone for every rollup to lock 10k Tezos sounds not realistic?

[Question from Agora](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/media-attention-regarding-tezos-mumbai-upgrade/5211)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1M TPS would be total throughput of 10k rollups.
So 1M TPS means 10M $XTZ staked, a little bit more than 10% of current supply. It doesn't sound so unrealistic.

I don't know any use case that need more than 2kTPS. 1M TPS is to read as a full potential brandwith for Tezos networks. Also we should not enphasys too much on "1 million", it is more to illustrate that horizontal scaling with Rollups is kind of limitless: there is no hard limit to 1 million